# more efficient regex to parse linux top command values

Tags: regex, linux, perl, optimization

I'm trying to grab some measurements on a per process level in this script I'm writing.  The easiest way to see the values I'm looking for is to just grab the output of the `top` command.

So when I try to parse it though, my regex looks kind of ridiculous.  Given this output:

```
  PID USER      PR  NI  VIRT  RES  SHR S %CPU %MEM    TIME+  COMMAND
 8364 cgroup_t  20   0  764m 646m 1520 R 101.7  4.3   0:05.51 perl
```

I came up with the regex to grab some values(the 8364 is passed in on a var and shown here for ease of reading and the top output is stored on a var called $top_string):

```
if($top_string =~ m/^\s*8364\s+([^\s]+)\s+([^\s]+)\s+([^\s]+)\s+([^\s]+)\s+([^\s]+)\s+([^\s]+)\s+([^\s]+)\s+([^\s]+)\s+([^\s]+)\s+([^\s]+)\s+([^\s]+)/){
    #return desired var number, ie.  $1,$2...etc
}
```

This works but it seems like overkill.  Is there any way to do this more efficiently?  I feel like maybe I remember a way to avoid typing the `\s+([^\s]+)` pattern over and over.

Anyway thanks for taking the time to read this!

Cheers

Comment: Note that a non-space character is matched by `\S`, so you could use `\s+(\S+)` instead. But `split` is the proper way to go

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use split when you have delimiter

```
my @cols = split ' ', ( $top_string =~ /(\d.+)/ )[0];
```

Comment: ah nice!  that is a much shorter expression!  thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if you're constrained to Perl or just wrote an easy script for this. In the second case, you can use `awk`, in which case it is direct:

```
{
    if ($1 == <process_value_here>)
    {
        print $1 /* Pid*/ "," $2 /*user*/ ...
    }
}
```

`awk` by default splits the input by spaces, so you have direct access to `$x`, with `x` being the number of the field.

Comment: unfortunately I am constrained in this instance to perl, however, I tossed your example in a quick bash script and it worked well.  +1

Answer (score 1):

As has already been said, just use [`split`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/split.html).  However, one tip is to limit the number of columns to 12 as the final column in a top command can contain spaces.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $top_string = do { local $/; <DATA> };

for my $line (split "\n", $top_string) {
    my @cols = split ' ', $line, 12;
    print "@cols\n" if $cols[0] =~ /^8364$/;
}

__DATA__
PID USER      PR  NI  VIRT  RES  SHR S %CPU %MEM    TIME+  COMMAND
 8364 cgroup_t  20   0  764m 646m 1520 R 101.7  4.3   0:05.51 perl
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider this a somewhat naieve response but this is something of a pet peeve of mine. I see a lot of people on Linux wanting to get information about a specific PID in their program and ignoring the existance of the /proc directory. Surely it was created for just this kind of thing (programtically extracting information about a particular process).

In order to get the info out of 'Top' you need to call the external program which requires a fork and all the subsequent code to manage that fork - maybe its easy in Perl but I'm used to C and in C thats more overhead then I'd like to deal with. Then you have to write a regular expression (queue the quote 'now you have two problems') to parse the output.

Reading directly from the /proc/ entry only requires standard file IO and the output from /proc is designed to be parsed programatically so shouldn't need complex RExp to deal with it.

Top on Linux reads from /proc internally to get its info anyway - so I can't see a good reason not to cut out the middleman here. only thing I can think of would be portability since some *Nixs don't have a /proc dir. But then again how portable is Top output (BSD top and GNU top probably subtly different anyway).

Comment: to generate the top string variable used in the question, its as simple as `my $top_string = \`top -b -n 1 -p $pid\`;` where $pid is the pid of the process.  Considering this will primarily be used for testing purposes, its really not that much overhead to worry about, at least with perl.  But testing purposes might explain why a lot of people on linux are happy just regexing against a top output.